# Laravel showing syntax error on line no 1 while it is working fine on my local system

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error when I upload Laravel to my production server

```
syntax error, unexpected 'EventController' (T_STRING)
```

Its working fine on my local server.

I have changed all DB parameters and routes, but this error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you absolutely sure that each server is running the same code?
- Could you tell us a little bit about the servers? (e.g. droplet, AWS, forge)
- Is there anything else in the logs, what log gives you this error?
- How are you putting your code on the server? (e.g. scm, ftp, ...)

My first instinct is that your two sources are not in sync. I would save everything commit/upload whatever your workflow entails and make sure it's up-to-date. Past that, possible version conflicts?

We're going to need a little more information to diagnose this.